# get valid startdate and enddate from data of table

Tags: sql-server

I have a table a, that show data of extending a loan :

| LoanId | GrantDate | OldDueDate | ExtendDate | NewDueDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-10-25 | 2022-12-14 | 2022-12-11 | 2023-01-13 |
| 1 | 2022-10-25 | 2023-01-13 | 2023-01-12 | 2023-02-13 |
| 1 | 2022-10-25 | 2023-02-13 | 2023-02-12 | 2023-03-16 |

Now, I want to have a new table, which gives me the valid start and end dates for each due date.
For Example, table b with this data:

| LoanId | StartDate | EndDate | ValidDueDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-10-25 | 2022-12-10 | 2022-12-14 |
| 1 | 2022-12-11 | 2023-01-11 | 2023-01-13 |
| 1 | 2023-01-12 | 2023-02-11 | 2023-02-13 |
| 1 | 2023-02-12 | 2023-03-16 | 2023-03-16 |

as you see in data, in the first row , startdate is GrantDate and enddate is previous day of first extension date,
in the second row , startdate is first extension date and enddate is previous day of second extension date,
in the third roe, startdate is second extension date and enddate is previous day of third extension date,
and in the last row, startdate is third extensiondate and enddate is final newduedate.

I try to write the query for this , but I can't do it right, because it has just 3 rows and i need 4 rows for this example.  what I did is like this :

```
Select LoanId,
       IsNull(Lag(ExtendDate) Over (Partition By LoanId Order By OldDueDate), GrantDate) as StartDate, 
       DATEADD(DAY,-1,ExtendDate) as EndDate, 
       OldDueDate as ValidDueDate
From a
```

can anybody help me?